# How to disable Clang warning "no case matching constant switch condition"

Tags: clang++, suppress-warnings

I am working on a project that uses code from another project, and that other code is giving me a bunch of warnings during compilation.  I don't want to change that code (my project is just a thin wrapper around their code and I want to be able to pull in updates without patching all the time) so I'd like to disable these warnings so I can focus on just my own code.

Unfortunately I can't see where this is documented!

The error I am receiving is:

```
warning: no case matching constant switch condition '2'
```

I have [looked in the manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wswitch) and tried `-Wno-switch`, `-Wno-switch-bool` and `-Wno-switch-enum` but none of them make this warning go away.  I can't see where in the manual this warning message is listed.

Using Google I haven't been able to find any command-line option that matches up with the error text.

Using GitHub I was able to find the LLVM source that [runs a test for this warning](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/f3b7928366f63b51ffc97e74f8afcff497c57e8d/test/SemaCXX/switch.cpp#L49) but I'm not having any luck mapping that back to a `-W` option to disable it.

What am I missing?

Here is some code that reproduces the error:

```
enum En { A, B, C };
template <En how> void foo() {
    int x = 0, y = 5;

    switch (how) {
        case A: x *= y; break;
        case B: x += y; break;
    }
}

template void foo<C>();

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no `-Wno-<what>` flag that can specifically suppress this warning.
If there was, then the diagnostic would be:

```
warning: no case matching constant switch condition '2' [-W<what>]
```

You can only suppress it by suppressing *all* warnings, with `-Wno-everything`,
which of course I would not advise.

Comment: What a shame!  Thanks for confirming, glad it wasn't me just looking in the wrong place!